# What is going on in this let expression?

Tags: haskell, syntax, let

I am reading through this [blog post](http://taylor.fausak.me/2014/10/21/building-a-json-rest-api-in-haskell/#transformers) about writing an API in Haskell with Scotty, and I came across the section on monad transformers. I understand the concept of monad transformers, but I cannot wrap my head around what's going on here:

```
let r m = runReaderT (runConfigM m) c
```

How can the expression reference `m` when `m` is declared in the same `let` expression that uses it? What is going on here? What is `m`?

Comment: `r` would be a function and `m` would be a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a (local) function declaration with the name `r`. `m` is the function's parameter. It's equivalent to:

```
let r = \m -> runReaderT (runConfigM m) c
```